# I guess this is easy for you => defining

Tags: python

i just started with Pyhton, coming from PythonKara and now i want it to randomly choose between some words:

```
from random import choice
Karten_Zwischenstand = 'a'
Karten_Zwischenstand = choice(['a','b','c', ... , 'y','z'])
```

in "..." the complete alphabet is there. This is not my exact programm, just an example of my case.

But i need to repeat this very often, so i wanted to define it, so i can get it with less space. I tried:

```
from random import choice
Karten_Zwischenstand = 'a'
def Karten:
   Karten_Zwischenstand = choice(['a','b','c', ... , 'y','z'])
Karten
print(Karten_Zwischenstand)
```

***So what i wanted, is that everytime, i write "Karten" in the programm, it takes a random letter.***
Like this we did definitions in PhytonKara, but in this programm it doesn't work, so how does it work here?

Comment: Any of the multitude of basic python tutorials on the web would show you what you're doing wrong. You need to learn the language.

Comment: In other news: Instead of enumerating all the letters you can import `ascii_lowercase` from the module `string`. It's what it sounds like: a string with all the lowercase ASCII letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to define a function:

```
def Karten():
    from random import choice
    Karten_Zwischenstand = choice(['a','b','c', ... , 'y','z'])
    return Karten_Zwischenstand

foo = Karten()
print(foo)
```

Comment: Why import inside the function here?

Comment: @Daenyth: There is no significant difference between doing the import inside and outside of the function for a program of this size.

Comment: Right but OP is clearly new to python, and it probably would be less confusing to display the normal way

Comment: Thanks, that was what i searched for, but no, it doesn't confuse me, when the import is in the definition :D I just couldn't find a solution how to do this, with google.